# Why does My Bot Keep Crashing (Cannot read property 'send' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```js
bot.on(`guildMemberAdd`, (member) => {
 const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor(`#ffffff`)
  .setAuthor(member.user.username)
  .setDescription(
   `Please read the <#762600414183948308> and get Free roles in <#763749111286464562>.`
  )
  .setTitle(`Welcome to **Fahad Kinq's Club!**`)
  .setImage(
   `https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/766990205931880480/769939170642362368/6826b0508f5b88a53774c7f574bd18dd.png`
  );

 member.guild.channels.cache.get(`762601972255162428`).send(embed);
});
```

> Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

All the code is right, and the channel id is correct. What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: are you sure that the channelID is correct? Your error means that no channel is found, that usually happens if the channelID is incorrect.

Comment: @WorthyAlpaca Yes! it was working a few hours ago :(

Comment: might be a little obvious but is the channel still there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like said in the comments, chances are that the channel does not exist, or your ID is invalid. Placing in a `return` statement is sometimes helpful to make sure that if there is no channel found, it'll stop the code, preventing the bot from crashing. Additionally, the method you are trying to use might be the issue itself. So, with these points in mind, the code is below

```js
bot.on(`guildMemberAdd`, (member) => {
// Define the channel
 const welcome = member.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.id === `762601972255162428`)
// What if it doesn't exist, or isn't found?
 if(!welcome) return;

// Create the embed
 const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor(`#ffffff`)
  .setAuthor(member.user.username)
  .setDescription(
   `Please read the <#762600414183948308> and get Free roles in <#763749111286464562>.`
  )
  .setTitle(`Welcome to **Fahad Kinq's Club!**`)
  .setImage(`https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/766990205931880480/769939170642362368/6826b0508f5b88a53774c7f574bd18dd.png`);

// Send the message
 welcome.send(embed)
});
```